# Quartz Scheduler Unresponsive

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm attempting to learn how to Quartz to schedule program runs. I'm running into a small problem though where it doesn't seem to respond to my input. I'm using the code below to create a simple example that should print "simple example" to the screen. However, once I set the time and run the program, nothing happens. I set it for two minutes out from the run and just wait, but it's not behaving as it should. I'm not getting any errors or anything, it's just doing nothing. I would appreciate any help.

```
package schedulers;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.CronTrigger;
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.SimpleTrigger;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.DateBuilder.*;

public class SimpleExample {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable{
     Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

        JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class)
            .withIdentity("cronJob", "testJob") 
            .build();

        String startDateStr = "2016-11-01 09:41:00.0";
       // String endDateStr = "2013-09-31 00:00:00.0";

        Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(startDateStr);
        //Date endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(endDateStr);

        CronTrigger cronTrigger = newTrigger()
          .withIdentity("trigger1", "testJob")
          .startAt(startDate)
          .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 9-12 * * ?").withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
          .build();

        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, cronTrigger);
        scheduler.start();
    }
```

}

```
package schedulers;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

/**
 * This class defines a quartz job.
 * @author 
 */
public class HelloJob implements Job{

public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("Simple Exapmle");    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scheduler will only start when start time is reached. The Only issue here looks your startdateStr. It may be not actual current date and that time is never reached to start the process. I tried your code by just replacing start date with below and worked fine for me.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date startDate = cal.getTime();
```

Also for quick result I changed cron to per 5 secs i.e. `"*/5 * * * * ?"`.

below is my result.

```
2016-11-01 10:20:28 INFO  StdSchedulerFactory:1339 - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
2016-11-01 10:20:28 INFO  StdSchedulerFactory:1343 - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
2016-11-01 10:20:28 INFO  QuartzScheduler:575 - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
Simple Exapmle
Simple Exapmle
Simple Exapmle
```

this might help you.

Comment: This helped a lot and the program ran. Thank you. However, I want to be able to schedule this to run on any given day or time. I am unsure how I could accomplish that with the code you provide.

Comment: Could I pass in a specific time to the Calendar object?

Comment: @Jrawr Even your code will work but when your systems time reaches your start time i.e. `2016-11-01 09:41:00.0`. Try to capture latest + some buffer in start time so that you can immediately see the results.

Comment: My code wasn't working at the provided start time though. That was the issue.

Comment: Tried your code with time changing to my system time and working perfectly fine. `startDateStr = "2016-11-01 10:51:08.0"` and process started at `2016-11-01 10:50:05 INFO  QuartzScheduler:575 - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.`

Comment: I get '135    [INFO] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.' however the job never runs so the "simple example" never prints. That's the problem I'm having. I changed my time to my system time and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. It seems that the problem lay in the Cron expression. Once I understood how to better construct them I could make them execute when I wanted. This helped a lot

```
"0 26 11 01 11 ?"
```